# How to use exec() system call to return the square of a number and store it to a file?

Tags: c, system-calls

Given a number in the command line by the user, I need to return the square of that number and store it into a file called `child.txt`, but I need to do this by creating a child process and using `exec()`. How exactly do I do that? Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   FILE *f;
   f = fopen("child.txt", "w");
   int pid = fork();
   square(argv);
   exec(); // This is wrong, I need to fix this
   return 0;
}

int square(char *argv[]) {
   int i;
   i = atoi(argv[1]);
   return i*i;
}
```

What parameters should I be passing into `exec()`? I've seen other examples where exec() has parameters such as `echo` or `-ls`, but is it possible to somehow pass in the `square()` function I've written?

Comment: `exec()` is actually used to start an *executable*. `square` itself is actually a function, so what you need to do is make it its own executable somehow.

Comment: Your question is like asking how to use a hammer to power a light bulb.  It really doesn't make any sense.  *Why* do you need to use `exec()`?

Comment: I'm sorry it's unclear, I was literally given two lines of instruction on the assignment. I can make a separate square.c, compile it and turn it into an executable, I just need an example of how exec() is used with this executable and then storing the output into a file.

Comment: I need to use exec() so I can understand it, just trying to learn.

Comment: Read [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) & [exec(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) `man` pages

Answer (score 1):

This is such a terrible idea for so many reasons....
But you can certainly do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int square(const char *arg) {
   int i;
   i = strtoll(arg, NULL, 10);
   return i*i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        FILE *f;
        char cmd[128];
        int rv;

        if( argc < 3 ) {
                fputs( "Please specify target file and integer to square\n", stderr);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        f = fopen(argv[1], "w");
        if( f == NULL ) {
                perror(argv[1]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        rv = snprintf(cmd, sizeof cmd, "echo %d >& %d", square(argv[2]), fileno(f));
        if( rv >= sizeof cmd ) {
                fputs( "Choose a smaller int\n", stderr);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", cmd, NULL);
        perror("execl");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

But note that if this is for an assignment and you've been told to use `exec*`, then this solution would be an `F` grade.  This is not what you're supposed to do.  (At least I hope not.  If that is the goal, then this is a terrible assignment.)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for taking the time to look at it anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make some calculation not in main thread, you can create thread and detach it.
If you use c11 compiler you can use threads.h.
`thrd_create` wil create your thread, `thrd_detach` will detach it from main process.

If your compiler doesn't support c11 you can use native multitreading options.

`#include <pthread.h>` for Unix systems

`#include <windows.h` for Windows